# deployment Failed with Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I am trying to deploy my code to azure app service using git. But I am getting error "deployment Failed with Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details". It was working perfectly 2 days back but suddenly it starts crashing.

There is nothing helpfull in logs.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/besYN.png)

Answer (score 12):

You can try the following workarounds to resolve this issue:

1. If you are using the VS code then use the `VS Code Azure Tool Extension`.
2. In App service -->go to the "Deployment Center" blade, and click on the "Disconnect" button on top.
   After that re-run the release pipeline.

Comment: Disconnecting the application from source control in the "Deployment Center", then de-deploying the app again worked for me. But it seems like it's not a permanent fix as I have had to do it several times already over the span of a few days (this was never an issue before a couple days ago). Do you know if this is a known issue, or even if there's a reason for it?

Comment: @agw2021, do you get any permanent solution for this ? I'm also facing the same issue.

Comment: Mr. patience's answer seems like a long term solution. It worked for me -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/75415822/2649145

Answer (score 6):

I created a function app both in the portal and in VS code then tried deploying via github action. I was able to repro that it fails to deploy to the function app create in the portal with the following errors:

[image]

The way to fix it was to add a setting in the configuration: ( and remembering to hit save )

[image]

After that, the github action runs correctly without any errors.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me when deploying from azure devops as well. Interestingly it only failed when deploying the first time to a deployment slot. When deploying without a deployment slot it seemed this setting was being added automatically.

Answer (score 3):

In Azure UI you can set this up in your `Environment variables`

`WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` = `1`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me it was `ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD` flag (in App Service Configuration) which was enabled on newly created function for some reason. I managed to find a reason after I've disabled it.
The requirements of my app failed to install and that's why build was failing.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the issue. I set `ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD=0` in the Settings-> Configuration blade of the Function App.
The setting applies to the deployment slot it seems.

Answer (score 1):

@nmishr's answer solved it for me.

If deploying as ZIP (e.g. from pipelines), and using bicep, I added the following app setting:

```
resource myWebApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' = {
  ...
  properties: {
    ...
    siteConfig: {
      ...
      appSettings: [
        ...
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE'
          value: '1'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error accompanied by several other messages on the output log.
One of the other messages was:

> Malformed SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE when uploading built content.

There is [another StackOverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017288/azure-function-deployment-failed-malformed-scm-run-from-package-when-uploading) which tries to solve this error.

When I tried to create a Function App through Azure Portal and then upload locally developed Functions to that Function App, I would get these errors.

My solution was to create the Function App through VSCode directly, using the VSCode Azure Extension.

Maybe this solution will work the same for App Services.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error twice in a row when attempting to re-deploy from the Azure extension within VSCode.  I had been attempting the deployment after first stopping the app service.  When I started the app service, then ran the deployment, it worked OK with no error.

I don't know whether that was the solution or whether something else happened in the background, because every time I deploy to Azure I get a different/new error or issue to overcome, but maybe this will help someone anyway.

Answer (score -3):

In the Function App portal, go to the "Deployment Center" blade, then click on the "Disconnect" button.

After that re-run the pipeline/release in AzureDevOps.