# Github Action for Azure App service fails

Tags: azure, github-actions, next.js13

I have a github action which deploys my next project to an Azure app service. It builds the Next project, deploys it on `staging` slot and then once that is completed, swaps it with the production slot.

I have gone through other answers on Stack Overflow, but cannot find a solution that works for me (some of the settings people have asked to change, I cannot find them in Azure Dashboard).

Please let me know if there are any further details needed and I will update the question.

Here is my Github Action file:

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set Node.js 16.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.x

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
      - name: Archive Build Output
        run: |
          zip -r build.zip . -x "*.git*"
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: build.zip # This will upload only the build.zip as an artifact

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: "dev"
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

      - name: "Deploy to Azure Web App"
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: "app-testing"
          slot-name: "staging"
          package: build.zip
        env:
          # list of env variables

      - name: Health check
        uses: jtalk/url-health-check-action@v1.2
        with:
          url: http://app-testing-staging.azurewebsites.net/health
          max-attempts: 2s
          retry-delay: 5s

      - name: Azure Swap Slots
        uses: azure/CLI@v1
        with:
          inlineScript: |
            az webapp deployment slot swap --slot staging --name kendal-testing --resource-group kendal --target-slot production
```

The above script was working till yesterday but I don't what has gone wrong since today.

Here is the error message from Github:

```bash
/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh: line 82:  2218 Killed                  "$KUDU_SYNC_CMD" -v 50 $IGNORE_MANIFEST_PARAM -f "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE" -t "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" -n "$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH" -p "$PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.sh"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Kudu Sync failed
/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh: line 82:  2218 Killed                  "$KUDU_SYNC_CMD" -v 50 $IGNORE_MANIFEST_PARAM -f "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE" -t "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" -n "$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH" -p "$PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.sh"\n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh "/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh"
Deployment Failed. deployer = GITHUB_ZIP_DEPLOY deploymentPath = ZipDeploy. Extract zip.
Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Error: Deployment Failed, Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
```

Not exactly sure if this is an issue in the action code or in the configuration of the app service, because it was working just fine 24 hours ago.

My App Service is on Standard S1 plan.

Screenshot of Deployment center. I could not find a Disconnect option as was suggested in an answer.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your GitHub repo if possible ?

Comment: `some of the settings people have asked to change`, what are the settings you are looking for ?

Comment: @Harshitha sorry cannot share the Github repo itself, its a private repo of the team. I can however, share any specific settings you might want to know in order to check what is causing the problem

Comment: @Harshitha - Also, these are the links

Firstly, I do not see the disconnect option mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72283661/13252221

Secondly, I do not see the `ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD` option mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75415822/13252221

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot where you are checking disconnect option.It is available only if you enable and add  the github account.

Comment: @Harshitha I have updated the question with the screenshot.

Comment: You are checking under logs tabs.Please check under settings.

Comment: @Harshitha thanks for the help, I connected Github and renamed my workflow file based on the requirement of azure (it has a particular naming template I noticed) and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what fixed my issue was connecting the Github workflow file to Azure App Service.

In Deployment Center, under Settings tab, I connected my project to azure using Github Auth. Then after selecting the project and changing the file name of the workflow file to the template that is required by Azure App Service, it worked.

Note: In case your App service cannot find the workflow file, disconnect it, rename the file to what Azure will recognise (you will see that name while disconnecting), and then rename and reconnect to Azure.