# Deploy Azure Function to Azure Environment with Python from VScode

Tags: python, azure-functions

I created a Azure function in VS code with Python, and tried to deploy to the Azure environment, but failed.

I created a function with Python from local, and didn't create the virtual environment, and it ran successfully from locally test, and I tried to deploy the function by clicking the deploy button (a cloud icon) from the WORKPLACE Local.

And the error output log:

```
2:09:44 PM liborwebapi: Starting deployment...
2:09:45 PM liborwebapi: Creating zip package...
2:09:45 PM liborwebapi: Zip package size: 4.84 kB
2:09:46 PM liborwebapi: Fetching changes.
2:09:47 PM liborwebapi: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/4d3064b9-1f05-4916-8f9c-c8bb81ad2edd.zip (0.00 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
2:09:49 PM liborwebapi: Updating submodules.
2:09:50 PM liborwebapi: Preparing deployment for commit id '365bc48a-c'.
2:09:50 PM liborwebapi: PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
2:09:50 PM liborwebapi: PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
2:09:50 PM liborwebapi: Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
2:09:50 PM liborwebapi: Running oryx build...
2:09:50 PM liborwebapi: Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.9.7 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
2:09:51 PM liborwebapi: Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
2:09:51 PM liborwebapi: You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
2:09:51 PM liborwebapi: Oryx Version: 0.2.20210120.1, Commit: 66c7820d7df527aaffabd2563a49ad57930999c9, ReleaseTagName: 20210120.1
2:09:51 PM liborwebapi: Build Operation ID: |HFvmXBsiIB0=.ddd78714_
2:09:51 PM liborwebapi: Repository Commit : 365bc48a-cb02-4d40-99b1-9c9b13aad2c1
2:09:51 PM liborwebapi: Detecting platforms...
2:09:51 PM liborwebapi: Detected following platforms:
2:09:51 PM liborwebapi:   python: 3.9.7
2:09:51 PM liborwebapi: Source directory     : /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
2:09:51 PM liborwebapi: Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot
2:09:52 PM liborwebapi: Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7/bin/python3.9
2:09:52 PM liborwebapi: Running pip install...
2:09:52 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:52+0000] Collecting azure-functions
2:09:52 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:52+0000]   Using cached azure_functions-1.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (206 kB)
2:09:52 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:52+0000] Collecting azf-wsgi
2:09:52 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:52+0000]   Using cached azf_wsgi-0.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.3 kB)
2:09:52 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:52+0000] Collecting pyodbc
2:09:52 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:52+0000]   Using cached pyodbc-4.0.34.tar.gz (271 kB)
2:09:53 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:53+0000] Collecting flask
2:09:53 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:53+0000]   Using cached Flask-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
2:09:53 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:53+0000] Collecting flask_cors
2:09:53 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:53+0000]   Using cached Flask_Cors-3.0.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
2:09:53 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:53+0000] Collecting datetime
2:09:53 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:53+0000]   Downloading DateTime-4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (52 kB)
2:09:53 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:53+0000] Collecting waitress
2:09:54 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:53+0000]   Downloading waitress-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
2:09:54 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:53+0000] Collecting click>=8.0
2:09:54 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:53+0000]   Downloading click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
2:09:54 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:53+0000] Collecting itsdangerous>=2.0
2:09:54 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:53+0000]   Downloading itsdangerous-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
2:09:54 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:53+0000] Collecting Werkzeug>=2.2.2
2:09:54 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:53+0000]   Downloading Werkzeug-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (232 kB)
2:09:54 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:54+0000] Collecting importlib-metadata>=3.6.0; python_version < "3.10"
2:09:54 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:54+0000]   Downloading importlib_metadata-4.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
2:09:54 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:54+0000] Collecting Jinja2>=3.0
2:09:54 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:54+0000]   Downloading Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
2:09:54 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:54+0000] Collecting Six
2:09:54 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:54+0000]   Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
2:09:54 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:54+0000] Collecting pytz
2:09:54 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:54+0000]   Downloading pytz-2022.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (500 kB)
2:09:55 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:55+0000] Collecting zope.interface
2:09:55 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:55+0000]   Downloading zope.interface-5.4.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (255 kB)
2:09:55 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:55+0000] Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.1.1
2:09:55 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:55+0000]   Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (25 kB)
2:09:55 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:55+0000] Collecting zipp>=0.5
2:09:55 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:55+0000]   Downloading zipp-3.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.6 kB)
2:09:56 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:56+0000] Collecting setuptools
2:09:56 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:56+0000]   Downloading setuptools-65.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
2:09:56 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:56+0000] Building wheels for collected packages: pyodbc
2:09:56 PM liborwebapi: [18:09:56+0000]   Building wheel for pyodbc (setup.py): started
2:10:02 PM liborwebapi: [18:10:02+0000]   Building wheel for pyodbc (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
2:10:02 PM liborwebapi: [18:10:02+0000]   Created wheel for pyodbc: filename=pyodbc-4.0.34-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl size=281778 sha256=bf4e3f13b3051b89bc5bb838cea799b00bd8f6535be474640942a874109e000a
2:10:02 PM liborwebapi: [18:10:02+0000]   Stored in directory: /usr/local/share/pip-cache/wheels/66/a1/a9/f74a4f22c1108fb47bfb125d510f5fcfe4ee0aca4eb76ec45e
2:10:02 PM liborwebapi: [18:10:02+0000] Successfully built pyodbc
2:10:02 PM liborwebapi: [18:10:02+0000] Installing collected packages: azure-functions, azf-wsgi, pyodbc, click, itsdangerous, MarkupSafe, Werkzeug, zipp, importlib-metadata, Jinja2, flask, Six, flask-cors, pytz, setuptools, zope.interface, datetime, waitress
2:10:05 PM liborwebapi: [18:10:05+0000] Successfully installed Jinja2-3.1.2 MarkupSafe-2.1.1 Six-1.16.0 Werkzeug-2.2.2 azf-wsgi-0.3.1 azure-functions-1.11.2 click-8.1.3 datetime-4.7 flask-2.2.2 flask-cors-3.0.10 importlib-metadata-4.12.0 itsdangerous-2.1.2 pyodbc-4.0.34 pytz-2022.2.1 setuptools-65.4.0 waitress-2.1.2 zipp-3.8.1 zope.interface-5.4.0
2:10:05 PM liborwebapi: WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
2:10:05 PM liborwebapi: You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
2:10:05 PM liborwebapi: Done in 14 sec(s).
2:10:05 PM liborwebapi: Preparing output...
2:10:05 PM liborwebapi: Copying files to destination directory '/home/site/wwwroot'...
2:10:05 PM liborwebapi: Done in 0 sec(s).
2:10:05 PM liborwebapi: Removing existing manifest file
2:10:05 PM liborwebapi: Creating a manifest file...
2:10:05 PM liborwebapi: Manifest file created.
2:10:05 PM liborwebapi: Done in 14 sec(s).
2:10:07 PM liborwebapi: Running post deployment command(s)...
2:10:07 PM liborwebapi: Generating summary of Oryx build
2:10:07 PM liborwebapi: Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
2:10:07 PM liborwebapi: The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
2:10:07 PM liborwebapi: Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
2:10:07 PM liborwebapi: Linux Consumption plan has a 1.5 GB memory limit on a remote build container.
2:10:07 PM liborwebapi: To check our service limit, please visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits
2:10:07 PM liborwebapi: Creating placeholder blob for linux consumption function app...
2:10:07 PM liborwebapi: Malformed SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE when uploading built content.
2:10:07 PM liborwebapi: Generating summary of Oryx build
2:10:07 PM liborwebapi: Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
2:10:07 PM liborwebapi: The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
2:10:07 PM liborwebapi: Deployment Failed. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
2:10:12 PM liborwebapi: Deployment failed.
``

What can I do?
```

Comment: How did you try to deploy it?

Comment: @RandomDavis, thanks for your quick response, and I just figured out the previous issue, and got the new issue (I edited the post) which I do have no idea what should I do for it...

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017288/azure-function-deployment-failed-malformed-scm-run-from-package-when-uploading) help?

Comment: After running "func azure functionapp publish <functionAppName> --build remote", I got error: 'liborwebapi' app is missing AzureWebJobsStorage app setting. That setting is required for publishing consumption linux apps. I have tried to set "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" in the local.setting.json file, but still failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is successful deployed in the context of Function App Created in the Portal and the default Http Trigger Python Azure Function Project in VS Code IDE > deployed through the Azure Tools extension:

```
7:02:27 am krishpyfuncapp: Starting deployment...
7:02:30 am krishpyfuncapp: Creating zip package...
7:02:30 am krishpyfuncapp: Zip package size: 1.69 kB
7:02:32 am krishpyfuncapp: Fetching changes.
7:02:33 am krishpyfuncapp: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/6bb139c0-e976-4810-a710-6974a06487a3.zip (0.00 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
7:02:35 am krishpyfuncapp: Updating submodules.
7:02:36 am krishpyfuncapp: Preparing deployment for commit id 'ef8271e2-4'.
7:02:36 am krishpyfuncapp: PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
7:02:36 am krishpyfuncapp: PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
7:02:36 am krishpyfuncapp: Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
7:02:36 am krishpyfuncapp: Running oryx build...
7:02:36 am krishpyfuncapp: Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.9.7 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
7:02:37 am krishpyfuncapp: Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
7:02:37 am krishpyfuncapp: You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
7:02:37 am krishpyfuncapp: Oryx Version: 0.2.20210120.1, Commit: <commit-id>, ReleaseTagName: 20210120.1
7:02:37 am krishpyfuncapp: Build Operation ID: |lc4FRPEluJU=.c145a923_
7:02:37 am krishpyfuncapp: Repository Commit : <commit-id>
7:02:38 am krishpyfuncapp: Detecting platforms...
7:02:38 am krishpyfuncapp: Detected following platforms:
7:02:38 am krishpyfuncapp: python: 3.9.7
7:02:38 am krishpyfuncapp: Version '3.9.7' of platform 'python' is not installed. Generating script to install it...
7:02:39 am krishpyfuncapp: Source directory : /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
7:02:39 am krishpyfuncapp: Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot
7:02:39 am krishpyfuncapp: Downloading and extracting 'python' version '3.9.7' to '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7'...
7:02:40 am krishpyfuncapp: Downloaded in 1 sec(s).
7:02:40 am krishpyfuncapp: Verifying checksum...
7:02:41 am krishpyfuncapp: Extracting contents...
7:02:44 am krishpyfuncapp: Done in 5 sec(s).
7:02:44 am krishpyfuncapp: Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7/bin/python3.9
7:02:44 am krishpyfuncapp: Running pip install...
7:02:45 am krishpyfuncapp: [01:32:45+0000] Collecting azure-functions
7:02:45 am krishpyfuncapp: [01:32:45+0000] Downloading azure_functions-1.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (206 kB)
7:02:45 am krishpyfuncapp: [01:32:45+0000] Installing collected packages: azure-functions
7:02:46 am krishpyfuncapp: [01:32:46+0000] Successfully installed azure-functions-1.11.2
7:02:46 am krishpyfuncapp: WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
7:02:46 am krishpyfuncapp: You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
7:02:46 am krishpyfuncapp: Done in 2 sec(s).
7:02:46 am krishpyfuncapp: Preparing output...
7:02:46 am krishpyfuncapp: Copying files to destination directory '/home/site/wwwroot'...
7:02:46 am krishpyfuncapp: Done in 0 sec(s).
7:02:46 am krishpyfuncapp: Removing existing manifest file
7:02:46 am krishpyfuncapp: Creating a manifest file...
7:02:46 am krishpyfuncapp: Manifest file created.
7:02:46 am krishpyfuncapp: Done in 7 sec(s).
7:02:47 am krishpyfuncapp: Running post deployment command(s)...
7:02:47 am krishpyfuncapp: Generating summary of Oryx build
7:02:47 am krishpyfuncapp: Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
7:02:47 am krishpyfuncapp: The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
7:02:47 am krishpyfuncapp: Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
7:02:47 am krishpyfuncapp: Linux Consumption plan has a 1.5 GB memory limit on a remote build container.
7:02:47 am krishpyfuncapp: To check our service limit, please visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits
7:02:47 am krishpyfuncapp: Creating placeholder blob for linux consumption function app...
7:02:47 am krishpyfuncapp: SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE placeholder blob scm-latest-krishpyfuncapp.zip located
7:02:47 am krishpyfuncapp: Writing the artifacts to a squashfs file
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Parallel mksquashfs: Using 1 processor
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Creating 4.0 filesystem on /home/site/artifacts/functionappartifact.squashfs, block size 131072.
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: [===============================================================|] 192/192 100%
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Exportable Squashfs 4.0 filesystem, gzip compressed, data block size 131072
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: compressed data, compressed metadata, compressed fragments, compressed xattrs
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: duplicates are removed
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Filesystem size 403.41 Kbytes (0.39 Mbytes)
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: 25.22% of uncompressed filesystem size (1599.31 Kbytes)
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Inode table size 1960 bytes (1.91 Kbytes)
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: 28.35% of uncompressed inode table size (6914 bytes)
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Directory table size 1959 bytes (1.91 Kbytes)
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: 33.72% of uncompressed directory table size (5809 bytes)
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Number of duplicate files found 3
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Number of inodes 216
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Number of files 195
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Number of fragments 14
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Number of symbolic links 0
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Number of device nodes 0
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Number of fifo nodes 0
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Number of socket nodes 0
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Number of directories 21
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Number of ids (unique uids + gids) 1
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Number of uids 1
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: root (0)
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Number of gids 1

7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: root (0)
7:02:48 am krishpyfuncapp: Uploading built content /home/site/artifacts/functionappartifact.squashfs for linux consumption function app...
7:02:49 am krishpyfuncapp: Resetting all workers for krishpyfuncapp.azurewebsites.net
7:02:49 am krishpyfuncapp: Deployment successful. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
7:03:18 am krishpyfuncapp: Syncing triggers...
7:03:21 am krishpyfuncapp: Querying triggers...
7:03:26 am krishpyfuncapp: HTTP Trigger Urls:
HttpTrigger1: https://krishpyfuncapp.azurewebsites.net/api/httptrigger1
```

As per my experience, I observed that creating the function app from portal and publishing from VS Code will give these kinds of errors sometimes.

From the VS Code Terminal, try using Azure Functions Core Tools or CLI or PowerShell cmdlets:

**AF Core Tools cmdlets:**

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
func azure functionapp publish krishpyfuncapp
```

Before running this cmdlet, make sure to activate the **`virtual environment`** in the VS Code Function Project:

```
python -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
```

This cmdlet taken from the [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-python?tabs=azure-cli,bash,browser) Reference.

[image]

**Cause 2**: It also might be regarding storage account connection string in the `local.settings.json`. Place the Azure Storage account connection string (i.e., associated with the function app) in `AzureWebJobsStorage` > Save and Deploy to function App using VS Code IDE.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, followed your instruction, I finally got ... new error. It shows `Upload completed successfully 
Deployment completed successfully.
Syncing triggers...
Functions in liborwebapi:`

and then I go to the functions to check, it shows:
`Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting.`

Comment: I am trying **WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAG** setting

Comment: Solved by manually upload zip to the container and set the value. Many thanks to your help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @user15410844, Great to hear that!